# Library fails to open COM port

Tags: c#, dll, serial-port

```
        port = 0;
        int openResult;

        openResult = 30;
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        try
        {
            comAddress = Convert.ToByte("FF", 16);
            baudRate = Convert.ToByte(5);
            openResult = StaticClassReaderB.AutoOpenComPort(ref port, ref comAddress, baudRate, ref comPortIndex);//automatically detects a com port and connects it with the reader
            openComIndex = comPortIndex;

            if (openResult == 0)
            {
                comOpen = true;
                openedPort = port;

                if ((cmdReturn == 0x35 | cmdReturn == 0x30))
                {
                    StaticClassReaderB.CloseSpecComPort(comPortIndex);//disconnects the reader from designated com port when communication error occurs
                    comOpen = false;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

        if ((openComIndex != -1) & (openResult != 0X35) & (openResult != 0X30))
        {
            comOpen = true;
        }

        if ((openComIndex == -1) && (openResult == 0x30))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Serial Communication Error", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

I see other uses having this same problem with the library. The full code can be found [here](https://www.ideyatech.com/blog/2016/09/21/guide-developing-software-solutions-rfid-technology/). My particular issue is trying to connect the reader using the application via the COM port. Firstly I tested the COM port independently using the Serial Port Monitor. Whenever an RFID tag is placed close to the reader the reader transmits this data over the COM port and the Port Monitor displays the ID of the tag. So I know the reader is functional.

However, when I use the library to connect, I find *openResult* returns 48 (dec)/0x30 (hex), which produces the error "Serial Communication Error". I am running this on Windows 10. How do I know if this library is no longer compatible with my system or can I alter the code to bring it up to date?

Comment: What is `StaticClassReaderB`?

Comment: @KlausGütter it is a class found inside the library, see the full code "here".

Comment: Ask library provider, unless this library is public. I assume it's the RFID reader  manufacturer should tell you what to do.

Comment: I found you the maker homepage. http://www.zk-rfid.com/en/service.php

Comment: @LouisGo thank you for the site. I have contacted them. Awaiting a response. I will post the solution once they get back to me.